# if/else Conditional Not Executing Correctly To Assign Variable Value

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, preg-match

I am simply trying to assign the class based on the `if()` statement `OR`s and a match with the `$pattern`. I've tried several direct matches and other methods.

I cannot get the `$boxclr` to assign based on the `OR`'s and `preg_match()`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$row['casetype_txt'] = $var; // $var = ADDICTION or GOTOBO etc..

$pattern = "/^".$_POST["loc_type"]."/"; // ADDI or GOTO etc... 

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// TYPE 1 /////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
if ( // TYPE 1 
preg_match($pattern, $row['casetype_txt']) 
AND 
   $row['last_action_txt'] == 'A' 
OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'B' 
OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'C'
OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'D'

)
{
 $boxclr = "type1"; // assigning class
} elseif ( // TYPE 1-2
preg_match($pattern, $row['casetype_txt']) 
AND
   $row['case_disp'] == 'C' 
OR $row['case_disp_txt'] == 'E' 
OR $row['case_disp_gp'] == 'F' 
OR $row['disp_act_txt'] == 'G' 

) { 
$boxclr = "type1-2"; // assigning class
}  
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// TYPE 2 /////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
elseif ( // TYPE 2
preg_match($pattern, $row['casetype_txt']) 
AND 
$row['last_action_txt'] == 'H' 
OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'I' 
OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'J'
OR $row['last_action_txt'] == 'K'
)
 {
$boxclr = "type2"; // assigning class
} elseif ( // TYPE 2-2
preg_match($pattern, $row['casetype_txt']) 
AND 
   $row['case_disp'] == 'C' 
OR $row['case_disp_txt'] == 'L' 
OR $row['case_disp_gp'] == 'M' 
OR $row['disp_act_txt'] == 'N' 

)
{ 
$boxclr = "type2-2"; // assigning class
} 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// TYPE 3 ////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
elseif...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, optimized it best I could, moved the repetitive `preg_match()` outside of the `IF`s and used `in_array()` for two of the conditions so you don't have to do multiple comparisons. The root problem was you were not using parentheses properly in your conditional statements so the ordering/precedence was off. The `preg_match()` move fixes that.

```
$row['casetype_txt'] = $var;

$pattern = '/^' . preg_quote($_POST['loc_type']) . '/'; // escape special chars

while ($row = @ mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) // I recommend not using @
{
    if (preg_match($pattern, $row['casetype_txt']))
    {
        if (in_array($row['last_action_txt'], array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')))
        {
            $boxclr = 'type1';
        }
        else if ($row['case_disp'] == 'C' || $row['case_disp_txt'] == 'E' || $row['case_disp_gp'] == 'F' || $row['disp_act_txt'] == 'G')
        {
            $boxclr = 'type1-2';
        }
        else if (in_array($row['last_action_txt'], array('H', 'I', 'J', 'K')))
        {
            $boxclr = 'type2';
        }
        else if ($row['case_disp'] == 'C' || $row['case_disp_txt'] == 'L' || $row['case_disp_gp'] == 'M' || $row['disp_act_txt'] == 'N')
        {
            $boxclr = 'type2-2';
        }
        // ...else if ()...
    }
}
```

Comment: cryptic ツ, wow.. this is pretty fancy. Really appreciate it. I will give this a shot and let you know.

Comment: I havn't been able to test it yet as I am waiting for some records to complete processing. I will certainly let you know. Thanks for asking. Really appreciate it.